# Flutter: Dynamic Widget as argument (A) of another widget (B), which Widget (A) receives an argument set on Widget B

Tags: flutter, widget, arguments

First of all, sorry about the title, sounds messy, but I hope someone already come across with this query. Will try to explain what I'm trying to achieve here.

I'm trying to reuse futureBuilder widget, as my app has lots of lists.

```
//flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StreamBuilderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream streamFunction;
  ScrollController scrollController;
  Widget customWidget;

  StreamBuilderWidget({
    this.streamFunction,
    this.scrollController,
    this.customWidget,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: streamFunction,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return IgnorePointer(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final item = snapshot.data[index];
                    return customWidget(item);
                        //PostItem(item) //example
                        //VideosItem(item) //example
                        //BooksItem(item) //example
                        ;
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My headache comes with the argument Widget, which I need to receive its own argument "item".

While reading this, seems to be fairly easy, although I could not get it solve.

A nasty work around is to replace the widget argument with a string argument, using it with a switch statement:

```
switch (widgetType) {
    case 'PostItemWidget':
        return PostItemWidget(post: item);
    case 'YouTubeItemWidget':
        return VideosItem(video: item)
    ... //and so on
```

You get the idea, anyway would be great to make it a more cleaver / clean solution.

Let me know if there's any further input you need.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Code Update. use like this

```
final item = snapshot.data
customWidget(item[index]['name'])

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StreamBuilderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream streamFunction;
  ScrollController scrollController;
  Widget customWidget;

  StreamBuilderWidget({
    this.streamFunction,
    this.scrollController,
    this.customWidget,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: streamFunction,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return IgnorePointer(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final item = snapshot.data;
                    return customWidget(item[index]['name']); ///use like that
                        //PostItem(item[index]) //example
                        //VideosItem(item[index]) //example
                        //BooksItem(item[index]) //example
                        ;
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mr-vd, thanks for the quick replay. Unfortunately, that does not work, as customWidget do not recognise the input of an argument. Thanks again.